# What is the proper method to Embed a Java Applet in an EXT-Gwt Container?

Tags: applet, gxt

I'm using Sencha EXT-Gwt and trying to embed a Java Applet in a ContentPanel.  I want the container to fill the whole screen (adding it to the rootpanel), and then i want the applet to be 100% width and height of the available space, minus whatever border, header, footer, etc I put in the Surrounding Ext widget.

When I try to do this intuitively, it results in the size of my applet overrunning the bottom of the container (i.e, the applet ends up bigger than the available space.  How do i get it to "stay" in it's available space?

```
    ContentPanel cp = new ContentPanel();
    cp.setHeading("Folder Contents");
    cp.setHeaderVisible(false);
    cp.setCollapsible(false);
    cp.setFrame(false);
    cp.setBottomComponent(toolBar);

    RootPanel.get().add(cp);

    cp.layout();
    cp.add(widgetAppletOne);
    cp.layout();
```

Thanks,

P

Comment: This only happens in Chrome.  In FF and IE, the ContentPanel ends up not taking up enough space (doesn't go 100% height), so obviously i'm just doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to use a FitLayout in a Viewport to achieve the full-browser window effect I wanted.

```
    ContentPanel cp = new ContentPanel();
    cp.setHeading("Folder Contents");
    cp.setHeaderVisible(false);
    cp.setCollapsible(false);
    cp.setFrame(false);
    cp.setBottomComponent(toolBar);
    cp.add(widgetAppletOne);
    cp.setLayout(new FitLayout());  

    Viewport v = new Viewport();  
    v.setLayout(new FitLayout());  
    v.add(cp);

    RootPanel.get().add(v);

    v.layout();
    cp.layout();
```